# How can the icon of airDatepickerInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

[image]

How can I change this icon to something else, like a an icon that represents reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This button is actually an `actionButton` with inputId `<ID>_button`, so the easiest way to change the icon is to update button server-side:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  airDatepickerInput(
    inputId = "mydate",
    label = "Select a dates"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("res")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  updateActionButton(session, "mydate_button", icon = icon("remove"))
  
  output$res <- renderPrint(input$mydate)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is there noway to initialize the button with a new icon? because there is a slight lag before the desired icon is displayed. during the lag, the old icon is displayed

Comment: Currently no, but you can open an issue in GitHub repo, I'll look at it